# How to fix problems with accent in words in code in R

Tags: r

I have a problem while coding in R. I have to use some cities names, and they have accent. But once I runned the code, the letter become ? and the code doesn't work anymore.

What I have :

`c_fill$city[c_fill$city == "SART?NE"] <- "SARTENE"`

What I want :

`c_fill$city[c_fill$city == "SARTÈNE"] <- "SARTENE"`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have 'encoding' issues. Have you tried saving all your code files as "UTF-8"?

Comment: @sindri_baldur I think that all of my codes are saved as UTF-8, but how I can verify ?

Comment: @sindri_baldur All of my codes are effectively in UTF-8

Comment: This is on Windows, I presume? other systems generally have no problems with encodings.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes this is on Windows

Comment: I think I can do it with iconv, but then my df become a value...

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example that gives the error? With perhaps a sample of your data.

Comment: @Joe I finally used another method, I don't have to write the accents anymore. But thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can recreate the script (copy and paste) and save it with the encoding "UTF-8".

Comment: No need for copy and paste, just do “save as” in your editor of choice.

Comment: I also met this problem when dealing with Chinese characters in R, even I saved the script in UTF-8. When I reopen the script , the characters will become "?". In this case, I'll replace the "?" in string and save the new script although this can be really troublesome.